# Powershell not recognizing legitimate commands when running batch file?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, scripting, cmd

As I'm just learning Powershell, I want to write a simple batch script that counts the number of lines in a text file and prints it to console window at the end. I wrote

```
Clear-Host
$counter=0
for /f %%j in (someText.txt) do (
    $counter++
)
$counter
```

I ran the script in Powershell and got the following error:
*'Clear-Host' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

'$counter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

'$counter++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

This is very befuddling to me, since when I enter individual commands like "$counter=0" and "$counter++" into Powershell, no errors occur and I get the expected behavior: I initialize a counter variable, and then increment it by one. 


Also, how do I enter an entire loop (or some other multi-line code construct) in Powershell?...entering it as a one-liner like `for /f %%j in (someText.txt) do ($counter++)` gives me 
*At line:1 char:4

+ for /f %%j in (someText.txt) do (

+    ~

Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.

At line:1 char:33

+ for /f %%j in (someText.txt) do (

+                                 ~

An expression was expected after '('.

At line:1 char:33

+ for /f %%j in (someText.txt) do (

+                                 ~

Missing closing ')' in expression.

    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword*

I also tried using cmd.exe instead of Powershell--I get all the same problems described above.
Any idea how I can make my script do what it's supposed to?

Comment: It looks like you've got some sort of batch/powershell hybrid. That will work about as well as using any two other languages in the same script - it won't.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have powershell at all...